# Lazy-Loading 3rd Party Service?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization, facade

There's a help service that I can load by putting this at the bottom of the `body` section on my home page:

```
<script async type="text/javascript">
    !function (e, t, n) {
        function a() {
            var e = t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], n = t.createElement("script");
            n.type = "text/javascript", n.async = !0, n.src = "https://beacon-v2.helpscout.net", e.parentNode.insertBefore(n, e)
        }

        if (e.Beacon = n = function (t, n, a) {
            e.Beacon.readyQueue.push({method: t, options: n, data: a})
        }, n.readyQueue = [], "complete" === t.readyState) return a();
        e.attachEvent ? e.attachEvent("onload", a) : e.addEventListener("load", a, !1)
    }(window, document, window.Beacon || function () {
    });
</script>
```

But loading it that way slows initial page load time and lowers my Lighthouse score.

I'd like to wait until my page has finished loading before calling this code.

Is it possible to get the same code to run inside of a React `useEffect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a `useInterval()` to call this code after the initial page load is complete:

```
// https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/
useInterval(() => {
    loadHelpChat();
}, 2000);
```

```
function loadHelpChat(){
    if (typeof(Beacon) !== "undefined") return;
    !function (e, t, n) {
        function a() {
            var e = t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], n = t.createElement("script");
            n.type = "text/javascript", n.async = !0, n.src = "https://beacon-v2.helpscout.net", e.parentNode.insertBefore(n, e)
        }

        if (e.Beacon = n = function (t, n, a) {
            e.Beacon.readyQueue.push({method: t, options: n, data: a})
        }, n.readyQueue = [], "complete" === t.readyState) return a();
        e.attachEvent ? e.attachEvent("onload", a) : e.addEventListener("load", a, !1)
    }(window, document, window.Beacon || function () {
    });
}
```

It seems like delaying the load by 2 seconds (that's the 2000 param sent to `useInterval()`) convinces Lighthouse that `loadHelpChat()` should not be considered part of the initial page load.